# As I click a link (which is a country name) I have the list of all cities, even from other countries. How to fix it?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have links (which are list of the countries) when I click (for example) "USA" I get list of the cities from other countries too. But I only want the list of the cities in the USA.

Here is my github link. You are welcome to clone and play with it.

https://github.com/ualmaz/post

I tried to filter that like this. queryset = Post.objects.all().values_list(
        'city', flat=True).distinct()

But it did not work.

This is my views.py

```
def cities(request):

    queryset = Post.objects.all().values_list(
        'city', flat=True).distinct()


    context = {
            'cities': queryset
    }

    return render(request, 'users/cities.html', context)
```

my models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="First name", max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="First name", max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(verbose_name="Country name", max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name="City name", max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:blog')
```

my countries.html (it contains countries list)

```
{% extends 'shared/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

<div class="content-section p-5 mt-5 pl-4">

<table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-6" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>No: </th>
          <th>Countries: </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

{% for post in posts %}

<table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-6" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
          <td><a href="{% url 'users:cities' %}">{{ post.country }}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

</div>
```

This is my cities.html (This is where I am having the problem)

```
{% extends 'shared/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

<div class="content-section p-5 mt-5 pl-4">

<table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-12" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 200px;">No: </th>
          <th> Cities: </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

{% for city in cities %}

<table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-12" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 200px;">{{ post.pk }}</td>
          <td>{{ city }}</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

</div>
```

Comment: post your `urls.py` also please.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not filtering by the `country` that you clicked on.  In your view, you should pass `country` in as a parameter.  You can then do `Post.objects.filter(country=country).values_list('city', flat=True).distinct()`, which filters posts by country instead of getting all of the posts.

Comment: I used your code and I get Name error: name 'country' is not defined :(

Comment: then you are probably not passing `country` as a parameter to the `cities` view.

Comment: U are my bro in Him. 

How do I pass 'country' as a parameter to the cities view?